# PHP $_POST['$var'] get the name of a dynamic php form

Tags: php, html

```
//this is the php code that i call in another file

    if ( isset($_POST['star'])){
        $check_vote = $_POST['star'];

        $new_rate = 0;
        ***$video1_id = $_POST["$video_id"];*** //the problem is here
        $find_video = mysqli($con, "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id='$video_id1'");

        // and this is the html code that another php function echoes//
```

```
form name='$video_id' method='POST'                             
input class='star star-5' id='star-5' type='radio' name='star' value='5'/>                              
<label class='star star-5' for='star-5'></label>                                
<input class='star star-4' id='star-4' type='radio' name='star' value='4'/>                         
<label class='star star-4' for='star-4'></label>                            
<input class='star star-3' id='star-3' type='radio' name='star' value='3'/>                             
<label class='star star-3' for='star-3'></label>
<input class='star star-2' id='star-2' type='radio' name='star' value='2'/>
<label class='star star-2' for='star-2'></label>
<input class='star star-1' id='star-1' type='radio' name='star' value='1'/>
<label class='star star-1' for='star-1'></label>    
<input type='submit' name='$video_id' value='Vote' id='$video_id'>                  
</form> 

// my problem is that i want to take the variable $video_id(either form the form either from the submit-button) to search for the specific video but i cant. i tried $video1_id = $_POST["$video_id"]; and $video1_id = $_POST['$video_id']; and this $video1_id = $_POST[$video_id]; and this $video1_id = $_POST['.$video_id'];
```

thnx for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can not get variable's value like `$_POST["$video_id"]` send it from a from with a field which is text or hidden field and get it another side.

Also you MUST divide your php code from html. "$blabla" is syntax error.
add php opening and closing tags to your php things like

so you can use your php code in html

for example

```
<h1><?=$video_id?> </h1>

<input type="hidden" name="vID" value="<?=$video_id?>" />
```

and get it like

```
$myVideoId = $_POST["vID"];
```

Comment: as i say in the comments this code is not html...is a php echo. it comes dynamically from a php function so i cannot do this <h1><?=$video_id?> </h1> and thats why i ask...the solution with the hidden field worked perfectly....thank you my friend...

Answer (score 0):

//the solution in the php echo html code was this...

```
form name='$video_id' method='POST'                             
input class='star star-5' id='star-5' type='radio' name='star' value='5'/>                              
label class='star star-5' for='star-5'></label>                                
input class='star star-4' id='star-4' type='radio' name='star' value='4'/>                         
label class='star star-4' for='star-4'></label>                            
input class='star star-3' id='star-3' type='radio' name='star' value='3'/>                             
label class='star star-3' for='star-3'></label>
input class='star star-2' id='star-2' type='radio' name='star' value='2'/>
label class='star star-2' for='star-2'></label>
input class='star star-1' id='star-1' type='radio' name='star' value='1'/>
label class='star star-1' for='star-1'></label>    
input type='submit' name='$video_id' value='Vote' id='$video_id'>                  
/form
```

//and the right php code in the other function was this

if ( isset($_POST['star']) && isset($_POST['video_id'])){
            $check_vote = $_POST['star'];

```
        $new_rate = 0;
        $video_id = $_POST['video_id'];
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id = '$video_id' ";
        $find_video = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```